# how to assign the hover to 2 elements

Tags: jquery

I am trying to assign hover event to 2 elements at the same time. Are there better ways to do this?

```
//I want to assign hover to another element.

$element1=$('hi');
$element2=$('hi2');


//I need to assign element 1 and element 2 to the same hover function... 
   $element1.hover(function(e){

       codes......

   })
```

Thanks for any helps.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: IMO, setting variables for individual elements, and then using .add to put them together goes against the whole point of awesome jQuery selectors.  I'd stick with binding against a selector that can select all the elements you want to bind an event to.  Again, just my opinion.

Comment: What type of element is `hi2`? `HTML6`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dPQuB/5/)**

```
$element1.add($element2).hover(function(e){

   codes......

 });
```

Or

```
$('hi, hi2').hover(function(e){

   codes......

 });
```

or If you want to do by the ids instead of hi

```
 $('#hi, #hi2')hover(function(e){

   codes......

 });
```

Comment: This does'nt even work, it's using `add()` the wrong way, see [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dPQuB/1/)

Comment: @adeneo: I fixed the fiddel: http://jsfiddle.net/dPQuB/2/ I applied the same syntax to the answer which should work now.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - Yes, now it uses add() the correct way, and it will work!

Comment: @adeneo you did not used my code, please check it over here, http://jsfiddle.net/dPQuB/3/

Comment: @Adil - That's not at all what your answer looked like, now you're using Francois edit in the FIddle, but good to see you got the point now ?

Comment: @adeneo: Well spotted, it is important to have the correct syntax.

Comment: @adeneo I have this $element1.add($element2).hover(function(e) and you made it like this $element1 = $("#test1");
$element2 = $("#test2");
$element1.add($element2);
$element1.css('color', 'red');

Comment: @Adil - My bad! It seems you're not getting it after all ?

Comment: @adeneo I got it now, you are right, infact there was as you pointed but it is fixed by some how. Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 3):

If hi and hi2 were actual elements then:

```
$('hi,hi2').hover(...
```

And by actual elements I mean

```
$('div,p').hover(...
```

would work, but based on your example I can't tell what `hi` and `hi2` are since they're not elements, classes, IDs or something else recognizable.

Answer (score 2):

So, let's say these are the elements you want to bind the hover to:

```
<div class="yay-for-hover">a</div>
<div class="yay-for-hover">b</div>
<div class="yay-for-hover">c</div>
```

You can bind with this selector in your jQuery:

```
$('.yay-for-hover').hover(function() {
    // Do stuff here.
});
```

I just went with class selectors, since to me, they make the most sense here.  If you want an element on your page to have the hover event triggered, just add the class to it.  Check out the [jQuery reference on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method, it constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those elements and the ones passed into the method, which means you can store the new set of elements in a variable or use it directly, like so:

```
var $element1=$('hi'),
    $element2=$('hi2');

$element1.add($element2).hover(function(e){

   codes......

});
```